# Excel sheet using pear

Tags: php

I am Generating excel sheet using pear in PHP.My question is how can i set uniform height for my All rows in my worksheet...??Any idea.

Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Try [using][1] `Worksheet::setRow`

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.php

[1]:

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the setRow method for the worksheet object? You can set the height of the row using that method.

Comment: Sorry for late reply..It sets height for one row at a time..I want the height to be set for all the rows in mu sheet

Comment: Yeah but what I was thinking is that everytime you add a row you just set the height at the same time. Or just loop through all the rows by number and set the height for that row. I couldn't think of anything that does it for all rows.